# Count the word with apostrophe as one word BUT returns two pieces of words (python)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am new in programming and I want to make a program that can count the frequency of words from a file. The expected output is as follows:

WORD FREQUENCY

```
in - 1
many - 1
other - 1
programming - 1
languages - 1
you - 1
would - 1
use - 1
a - 4
type - 1
called - 1
list’s - 1
TOTAL = x
```

I've almost got it working, but the word "list's" returns something like this:

```
list**â**  -  1
s  -  1
```

affecting the number of total words from the file.

I've been using regex like this:

```
match_pattern = re.findall(r"\w+", infile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that a simple expression with a `defaultdict` might work:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

regex = r"(\b\w+\b)"
test_str = "some words before alice and bob Some WOrdS after Then repeat some words before Alice and BOB some words after then repeat"
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print(matches)

words_dictionary = defaultdict(int)
for match in matches:
    words_dictionary[match]+=1

print(words_dictionary)
```

#### Normal Output

```
['some', 'words', 'before', 'alice', 'and', 'bob', 'Some', 'WOrdS', 'after', 'Then', 'repeat', 'some', 'words', 'before', 'Alice', 'and', 'BOB', 'some', 'words', 'after', 'then', 'repeat']

defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'some': 3, 'words': 3, 'before': 2, 'alice': 1, 'and': 2, 'bob': 1, 'Some': 1, 'WOrdS': 1, 'after': 2, 'Then': 1, 'repeat': 2, 'Alice': 1, 'BOB': 1, 'then': 1})
```

#### Test with `lower()`

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

regex = r"(\b\w+\b)"
test_str = "some words before alice and bob Some WOrdS after Then repeat some words before Alice and BOB some words after then repeat"
matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print(matches)

words_dictionary = defaultdict(int)
for match in matches:
    words_dictionary[match.lower()]+=1

print(words_dictionary)
```

#### Output with `lower()`

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'some': 4, 'words': 4, 'before': 2, 'alice': 2, 'and': 2, 'bob': 2, 'after': 2, 'then': 2, 'repeat': 2})
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UGonuH/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/UGonuH/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

---

```
for key,value in words_dictionary.items():
    print(f'{key} - {value}')
```

#### Output

```
some - 4
words - 4
before - 2
alice - 2
and - 2
bob - 2
after - 2
then - 2
repeat - 2
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer, however the output should look exactly like the illustration above :( will try this, though.

Comment: perhaps a Counter from collections, https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#counter-objects

Comment: Hey Emma! A little update: It works!! but, it's still returning something like this: list**â**  -  1
s  -  1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
match_pattern = re.findall(r"\w+", infile)
```

Try use:

```
match_pattern = re.findall(r"\S+", infile)
```

`\w` maens a-z A-Z _ 0-9

`\S` means any non space character.

Comment: It worked, however there's a catch... periods shouldn't show on the results. it should only look like this: frequency - 1 (instead of "frequency. - 1")

Comment: @noobatprogramming. you use the regex to find words. no?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that does not use regex.

I am assuming there are multiple sentences in the file. Take the whole content as docstring and use `str.split()` function with split by space. You will get a list of words in that string.

Next you can use `collections.Counter(list)` to get a dictionary which has keys as words and values as their frequency.

```
from collections import Counter
with open('file.txt') as f:
  a = f.read()
b = dict(Counter(a.split(by = ' ')))
```

b is dictionary with the word-frequency pairs.

Note - Periods will always be kept with the last word in the sentence. You can ignore them in the results, or you can remove all periods first and then do the above procedure. Then the '.' used in abbreviations will also be removed, so it may not work like you want.

If you still want to use regex and match letters and apostrophe, try 
r"[a-zA-Z']+" and then use Counter. I will try to post some code for it when I get some time.

Comment: Hey there! Yes, the file contains 2 sentences, one apostrophe and 2 periods. I will try this method too and I'll get back to you. Thank you so much!

Comment: @noobatprogramming How did it go? Has it solved your problem?